# .com.mysql.jdbc.exception.jbbc4.communicationexception..communication link failure

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc

I have got above message when I try to work with database connected java application.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Here I will mention some java code in my java application; that I used to connect with database.

jDBC driver name and database URL

```
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/SORTS";
```

user and password

```
static final String USER = "root";
static final String PASS = null;
```

Register JDBC driver

```
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

//"Connecting to a selected database..."

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
```

I think these MySql server information also may be useful

```
current database:sorts
current user:root@localhost
Connection:localhost via TCP/IP
TCP port:3307
```

Answer (score 0):

In the URL, you should add the port number used, 3307 (which is not the standart one...):

```
 static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/SORTS";
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your database is running? Check and make sure your database server is up and running. Also, take into consideration tacou_st aswer